# Edit and save same xml file ruby

Tags: ruby, xml

I have written a code that remove comments on xml file, how can i save it as an xml file again. Currently i read the xml file as a text file. When i run this code on the console it outputs the xml content, but on the newexample.xml it prints out this : `**#<File:0x00000002b8be40>**` How can i print it as an xml file? please help

xml before edited

```
 <!--
    <product>
      <name>PC</name>
      <price>R100</price>
    </product>
   -->
```

Output: xml after editing

```
       <product>
          <name>PC</name>
          <price>R100</price>
        </product>
```

here is the code

```
file = File.open('C:/ruby/example.xml','r+') do |file|
    file.each {|line| line.gsub(/^\s\W*\s$/, " ")}

end


 File.open("newexample.xml","w") do |f|
    f.write file 
end
```

Comment: Provide sample input and expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

file_path = 'C:/ruby/example.xml'

File.open(file_path, 'r') do |file|
  @a = file.map{ |line| line.gsub(/^\s\W*\s$/, " ") }
end

File.open(file_path, 'w') do |file|
  @a.each { |e| file.puts e }
end
```